# Problems with the Javascript proxy pattern

Tags: javascript

Hi would like to create a function that takes one argument (a function) and proxies the function:

```
function proxyFunc(func) {
  console.log("Proxying ", func.name);
  var proxied = func;
  func = function() {
   console.log("Calling proxied ", func.name);
   return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}
```

Unfortunately the proxying does not work. I already figured out that the assignment of the proxy function to the original function is the problem, but I don't know how to make it work:

```
func = function() { ... }
```

Comment: You need to return `func`, otherwise your `proxyFunc` has no effect.

Comment: I want to intercept calls to methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
function proxyFunc(original) {
    console.log("Proxying ", original.name);
    return function() {
       console.log("Calling proxied " + original.name);
       return original.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

For what you're doing, this will help:

```
function proxyMember(obj, member) {
    var original = obj[member];
    console.log("Proxying ", member);
    obj[member] = function() {
       console.log("Calling proxied " + member);
       return original.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}

proxyMember(obj, "foo");
```

Comment: This can be used as `Object.func1 = proxyFunc(Object.func1)` but I would like to skip the assignment

Comment: @nrabinowitz: Note that you can set `name` by using `var f = function foo(x) { ... }`, instead of setting it manually.

Comment: @Erik: You can't. Javascript doesn't pass arguments like that.

Comment: @Eric - huh, never knew that. But note that [MDN marks this as non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), and it isn't part of the ECMAScript spec. That page also explains why my approach didn't work, as the property (in implementing interpreters) is read-only.